# How to improve spell check in OS X

Tags: macos, spellcheck

When I write a letter my workflow is like this.  I type sentence.  Some words end up underlined red.  I right click on the underlined words and select the correct spelling.

The problem is that the quality of suggestions that I get is really low.  Often, the correct spelling is not suggested even though it's one or two [edit operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) away.  When I paste the same misspelled word into google, it finds the correct spelling immediately.  That, of course, is prohibitively time consuming.   I mean, if general search the internet performs better, the built in algorithm is really awful

So, how can I improve the quality of spelling suggestions?  Is there a way to plug in a different algorithm or a different dictionary?

Comment: What apps are you talking about?  Office and some others use totally different stuff than what apple provides.

Comment: It is actually possible to write custom spell servers, and people have ported better algorithms. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/455558/cocoaspell-successor-improved-spell-check-for-m1-macos-13#comment663771_455558

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative is Spellcatcher X.

http://www.rainmakerinc.com/products/spellcatcherx/

**Update**

Unfortunately, Spellcatcher X is no longer supported. However, it is still available for download on a number of sites, such as [MacUpdate](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/10590/spell-catcher-x).

**Note:** This will only run on Intel Macs with older versions of macOS (i.e. it is a 32-bit app and will only work up to and including macOS 10.14 Mojave)