# What can I do to improve Apple's spellcheck?

Tags: spellcheck

I use a variety of tools for writing, many of which have their own spellcheck or grammar check functionality, and am pretty consistently impressed by how good these are (Google Doc for example is great, as are most IDEs). But Apple's spellcheck is consistently abysmal, both on iOS and macOS. It routinely proposes incorrect "corrections" and fails to assist with even the most rudimentary typos, often failing tp provide any suggestion at all or — worse — promising a substitution that is clearly inappropriate. For some reason, it seems worse in Messages and Mail than in Safari (e.g. composing here, of that's using Apple's).

Is there anything I can do to improve Apple's spellcheck? It's gotten to the point that it's interfering rather than helping.

Comment: Not found many spellchecks in anythings that gets all in this: Eye Halve a Spelling Chequer
Eye halve a spelling chequer
It came with my pea sea
It plainly marques four my revue Miss steaks eye kin knot sea.
Eye strike a quay and type a word And weight four it two say Weather eye am wrong oar write It shows me strait a weigh.
As soon as a mist ache is maid It nose bee fore two long
And eye can put the error rite Its really ever wrong.
Eye have run this poem threw it I am shore your pleased two no Its letter perfect in it's weigh
My chequer tolled me sew.

Comment: @Allan No (clearly) that's about finding an alternative, this is specifically about improving the Apple spellchecker where I'm stuck with it.

Comment: That too, has [already been asked](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/214835/119271).  Since the spell checker hueristic engine cannot be modified, the *only* option to to use an alternate.   As you’ve demonstrated, it cannot recognize potential correct spellings, so, adding a dictionary (the only thing you can actually change) isn’t going to solve the issue. The logic of the engine - finding potential corrections - is what’s defective. Unfortunately, it can’t be improved by the user.

Comment: @Allan Using example from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345456/macos-built-in-spell-checker-performs-badly-what-can-i-do?noredirect=1&lq=1 can it be verified base hunspell algorithm exhibits same issue as well?

Comment: I feel your pain. Apple's spellchecking implementation is one of the few areas I feel that others (e.g. Microsoft) have done a much better job on. Unfortunately, though, @Allan is correct. This question has been asked before and answered. The only thing I would strongly encourage is that you provide your [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) to Apple. I would definitely start with the iOS feedback options first (e.g. Messages) and then also via the macOS options as well. All the best!

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean “can it be verified base hunspell algorithm…”.   It’s the one in use and interestingly enough, in researching this bit of info, Hunspell was originally based on the [Hungarian language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunspell). Could that be the reason it’s so horrible?  Possibly…